# Resources for learning about the Gurgenidze System of the Caro-Kann as Black

Tags: opening, books

I'm ~1900 rapid on Lichess. As Black, I like to play this defense against `1.e4` (picked up from watching Hikaru's streams):

```
[FEN ""]
1.e4 g6 2.d4 Bg7 3.Nc3 c6 4.Nf3 d5 (4.f4) (4.Be3)
```

Are there any books or online resources available for learning more about this defense and the strategic ideas behind it?

Answer (score 3):

This video gives some insight into black's ideas
[Chess Opening for Black: The Gurgenidze System](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r07qvSgTOQ8)

a well known idea is to exchange the c8 Bishop with the help of h5 when white goes for f4 and then e5 after black plays d5

```
[FEN ""]
1.e4 g6 2.d4 Bg7 3.Nc3 c6 4.f4 d5 5.e5 h5 6.Nf3 Bg4 7. Be3 Nh6 8. h3 Bxf3 9. Qxf3 Nf5 10. Bf2 h4 11. Bd3 e6
```

The g7 bishop will re-route to e7 giving extra support on h4. You could even delay playing Bg7 early so you can play Be7 straightaway without losing tempi.